# SBT not working Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to run a scala project with spark. I did the following in my file:

```
package com.sparksql.count
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
```

However it told me that log4j and spark cant be found. I did a bit of research and figured it must have been the sbt. I then went to the SBT and i added in the library dependency as below

```
name := "SampleLearning"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

However, it still cant work and says there is something wrong with librayDependencies. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

- Spark doesn't support Scala 2.12. To work with Spark use Scala 2.11
- Spark 1.2 hasn't been supported in years. Use either 2.x branch (latest is 2.3.0) or (for legacy application) latest 1.x release (1.6.3) but it is quite outdated today.

Comment: I see no wonder. Ok i have already downgraded scala to 2.11.8. I tried to add the libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0" in my sbt.build but still its very slow to auto import.

Comment: It will be slow to import first time, Spark has to be downloaded. And don't use 1.2.0. Replace that with 2.3.0.

Comment: Hi all thanks. I was able to do that with this:

name := "learning project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"

however, it still reads it cant read symbol spark.conf